# Ubuntu downgrade on encrypted drive

Tags: encryption, vpn, luks, aws, downgrade

On my laptop I have dualboot with win10. Win10 partition is encrypted with Bitlocker and Ubuntu partition is installed on encrypted LUKS partition (boot is not encrypted, home and other folders are in one encrypted partition).
Recently I upgraded system to 22.10 and sadly noticed that AWS VPN Client is not supported on this system version. I need to downgrade back to 22.04 LTS.
I have a question if I can downgrade Ubuntu (preferably using standard installer) from 22.10 to 22.04 on this encrypted LUKS drive without decrypting it first?
I would really like to do this without touching current disk configuration.
Thanks!

Comment: You can not down grade Ubuntu you must install 22.04 if that is the version you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can I install on previously encrypted hard drive without decrypting it?

Comment: I do not use encryption and do not know. Maybe someone else will read this and have an answer. You may want to change the title to reflect the updated question.